# QListWidget item isn't added (Multiple Selection)

Tags: c++, qt

So given the below code which transfers items from one `lstWidget` to another, I seem to have an issue with not all of the selected items being transferred.

```
void winSample::on_btnMoveSingle_clicked()
{
   QModelIndexList indexes = (ui->lstImported->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes());
   foreach( QModelIndex index, indexes)
   {
       ui->lstSample->insertItem(ui->lstSample->count(),
       ui->lstImported->takeItem(index.row()));
   }
   updateView();
}
```

Its really strange and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. If I select more than one item there is always a few that don't get moved to the other listWidget.

Would appreciate any advice/feedback

Answer (score 0):

After you are doing `takeItem` your `indexes` list becomes invalid. Take a look at `QPersistentModelIndex`.

From my point of view it is bad idea to do such transfer. I propose you to copy items from one list to another, and then remove selected items from the first list.